# Eigen tensor broadcasting syntax

Tags: c++, numpy, eigen

I have the following numpy code:

```
# q.shape == (fxs, ks)
# E.shape == (fxs, fxs)
C = q[:, np.newaxis, :] * E[:, :, np.newaxis] * q[np.newaxis, :, :]
# C.shape == (fxs, fxs, ks)
```

which I am reimplementing in Eigen.

Here's what I came up with:

```
Eigen::Tensor<T, 3> C =
          q.reshape(Eigen::array<int, 3> {fxs, 1,   ks}).broadcast(Eigen::array<int, 3> {1, fxs, 1})
        * E.reshape(Eigen::array<int, 3> {fxs, fxs, 1 }).broadcast(Eigen::array<int, 3> {1, 1, ks})
        * q.reshape(Eigen::array<int, 3> {1,   fxs, ks}).broadcast(Eigen::array<int, 3> {fxs, 1, 1});
```

but this seems pretty verbose. Is this the right translation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the xtensor C++ template library, which supports both dynamic and static dimensions http://xtensor.readthedocs.io

xtensor has an API that is very similar to that of numpy, including vectorization, broadcasting, universal function. There is a numpy to xtensor cheat sheet here: http://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html

Finally, you can try it live in a C++ Jupyter notebook by clicking on the binder badge at the top of https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor/

xtensor also comes with bindings for the main languages of scientific computing (R, Julia, Python).